# Getting warning message while Pushing a View

Tags: iphone, ipad, uinavigationcontroller

In my application I want to push a different view from the ViewWillAppear of my current view.
Application is running but I am getting a message in console is that

Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted.

Can you help me.

Comment: could you add some code where the pushing occurs?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301014/ios-popviewcontroller-unexpected-behavior

Comment: - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    
 Aview* aObj = [[NRInstructionScreenVC alloc]initWithNibName:
                                             @"Aview" bundle:nil];   [self.navigationController pushViewController: aObj animated:YES];
[aObj release];  

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In absence of some requested code I'll take a guess that you push your new viewController with the animated flag to YES. In that case set your previous ViewControllers transition to nonanimated. In other words(code):

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:firstViewController animated:NO];
```

in its (firstViewController) ViewWillAppear:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:secandViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks a Lot.It is working.But if you provide the reason then I am grateful to you.

Comment: in ViewWillAppear you push your nextViewController. So nextViewController gets added to the navigationstack before previousController hence the corruption