# Error: "nested pop animation can result in corrupted navigation bar"

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

i try to get the text of a cell from a table (in ViewController B) and to display it in a textView (in ViewController A). Everything is fine the first time but when second time a have an error message in the console:
"nested pop animation can result in corrupted navigation bar
Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted."

My code is :
In ViewController B

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
// Retrieve the value of cell selected
self.valeurCell = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].textLabel.text];

// Send the value of cell in the answer area (class: SendMessagesViewController)
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"notice" object:self.valeurCell];
```

}

In ViewController A
(viewDidLoad)

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(dataTransfer:) name:@"notice" object:nil];


-(void) dataTransfer:(NSNotification *) sentObject{

// !!! en test !!!
self.textViewMsg.text = (NSString *) [sentObject object] ;
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

}

Thank you

Answer (score 6):

To make  pop or  push of ViewController before **viewDidAppear** is not safe. Perform this code [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]; after viewDidAppear() was called.

Comment: i tryed to put the code [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]; in "viewDidAppear"  but doesn't work

Comment: Maybe you try to pop view controller before previously created controller still animated, take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301014/ios-popviewcontroller-unexpected-behavior

Answer (score 1):

I have customized my UITabbarController, and I found out that in my **viewDidAppear** function,

I didn't put `[super viewDidAppear:animated];`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if still usefull, but the easiest answer I can think of is that you take the

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

to the end of your `didSelect` method, in viewControllerB.

Hope it helps!